# Moving iTunes library after crashed Windows drive

Tags: itunes, migration

I've read many questions and answers here about moving iTunes libraries between computers and drives. My situation is a little different though. I have (had) Windows XP with iTunes installed on C: and my iTunes library on a second drive (E:). Drive C: crashed recently.

My plan is to move my iTunes folder from drive E: to an external backup drive, re-install Windows onto drive E: (obviously it will now be drive C:) and then copy my iTunes library onto drive C:. I would then configure iTunes to point to C: drive for the library. From what I've read, this should work.

Where are all my podcast subscriptions stored? Where are all my ratings and play-counts stored? Will they still be in iTunes after I've followed these steps?

**Edit:** Further reading has made me aware of the Media and the Library folders. As far as I know, all my library files (music and podcasts) are located in the iTunes folder on E: drive.

**Edit:** I have a backup image of the C: drive from about six weeks ago, so I should be able to access files from there if I need to to restore metadata?

Answer (score 1):

By your method , backup and restore the library and files, definitely works . It saves all the playlists, playcounts, music, movies, ratings everything.

Answer (score 0):

Because my music and podcasts were stored on the `E:` drive, I needed to also copy the iTunes metadata folder under `My Documents`. I had a backup of this from a few weeks ago. The iTunes Library file(s) there reference all music and podcasts as being on the `E:` drive, which is where they were. Instead of editing that file, I used the `subst` command in Windows to create an `E:` drive which just referenced `C:`. After installing iTunes and copying the iTunes metadata folder into `My Documents`, I launched iTunes and my music and podcasts appeared.

My understanding is that if music and podcast files are not stored in an alternate location, simply copying the `iTunes` folder under `My Documents` as described in the [official](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527) documentation is sufficient. My music and podcasts were stored in an alternate location (`E:`), which additionally no longer existed after the reinstall.